# R console in terminal. Error: R function requires 1 argument

Tags: r

I'm running fedora 21. R Studio works fine at Version 0.99.447.

I have the executable `R` but when I try to open it, it gives me the message:

`R function requires 1 argument`

When I try to get the version of R from the terminal nothing returns.

Any idea what the problem is?

I'm trying to have a console just like in R Studio where I can interact with the terminal entering function, evaluation expressions and so on.

All around the web it says that I just need to type `R` into the terminal, but that is not the case for my setup.

Let me know if you need some other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that this issue was because of a plugin I had enabled on Bash it.

https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it

I just opened an issue at https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/issues/586

For a workaround just disable the plugin:

`rm ~/.bash_it/plugins/enabled/dirs.plugin.bash`

That does it for now.